# Pickling Selenium Webdriver Objects

Tags: python, selenium, serialization, selenium-webdriver, pickle

I want to serialize and store a selenium webdriver object so then I could use it later elsewhere in my code. I'm trying to use pickle to do this. If there is another way to save the state of a webdriver object, so I can bring it up again later, that'd be great (I can't just reload the url, since the websites I am looking at are javascript-heavy and the current page depends on what I've clicked on so far).

Currently, I have code like this.

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.PhantomJS()
d.get(url)
d.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
p = pickle.dumps(d, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
# Stuff happens here.
new_driver = pickle.loads(p)
print new_driver.page_source.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

When I run this, I get the following error (the error occurs when I print, not before):

```
    return self.driver.page_source.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
File "/home/eric/dev/crawler-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 436, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
File "/home/eric/dev/crawler-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 163, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/home/eric/dev/crawler-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
File "/home/eric/dev/crawler-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 396, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Is it possible to serialize my webdriver objects? If not, what are my alternatives?

**UPDATE:**

Upon further inspection, even if I do something like d.get(url) again instead of printing the page source, it gives me the same error. Does something happen to the webdriver object when it is pickled/unpickled?

Comment: I really don't think this is doable. Can you just keep webdriver up-and-running?

Comment: Certain things are non-serializable, such as socket connections. Since the WebDriver likely is using socket connects (or some other sort of inter-procedural call) to the web browser, it is not possible to serialize it.

Comment: @alecxe I was thinking of doing that, but i need to jump around different web pages whenever, so I can't do something like follows: "Go to page x, click on y, click on z" wait and then come back and say "click on w to go to page y" --

@robbrit If I look at the `__dict__` of the webdriver and look at the `__dict__` of those objects and so on, aside from a File Object, there isn't anything that isn't just strings or tuples of strings. I don't entirely know much about the makeup of python objects, but is there more to the objects than the stuff in the `__dict__`?

Comment: You might want to try `dill`.  It can serialize most python objects, and can serialize file handles and socket connections.  Upon pickling, `dill` does not 'forget' dynamically added attributes on instances, so if that's what's going wrong, it won't be a problem either.  Might be worth a try.  Get `dill` here https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: `dill` also includes a suite of tools that help find out why the object is failing to serialize.

Comment: The webdriver serializes fine (at least I think. There aren't any errors or anything upon serializing).
Is it as simple as switching to dill? Because that doesn't seem to have helped ("import dill as pickle" and then run the code exactly like before).

Comment: Update: So I have realized that it is probably useless the pickle the webdriver. All the webdriver does (if I understand this correctly) is interact with (drive) a browser, such as PhantomJS. So I guess that would mean it'd be nice to save a page in a browser, but I can't really do that normally using the browser (if the page doesn't depend on the url).

Answer (score 5):

I was able to pickle a selenium.webdriver.Remote object. Neither dill or pickle worked for me to serialize a selenium.webdriver.Chrome object, in which python creates and runs the browser process. However, they both worked if I (1) ran the standalone java selenium2 webserver, (2) in one process, create a selenium.webdriver.Remote connection to that server and pickle/dill that to a file, (3) In another process, unserialize the Remote instance and use it.

This led to being able to close the python process and then re-connect to the existing webdriver browser and issue new commands (could be from a different python script). If I close the selenium web browser then a new instance needs to be created from scratch.

server.py:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver

EXECUTOR = 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'
FILENAME = '/tmp/pickle'

opt = selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
capabilities = opt.to_capabilities()
driver = selenium.webdriver.Remote(command_executor=EXECUTOR, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
fp = open(FILENAME, 'wb')
pickle.dump(driver, fp)
```

client.py:

```
import pickle

FILENAME = '/tmp/pickle'

driver = pickle.load(open(FILENAME, 'rb')
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
el = driver.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
print(el)
```

Note (2020-08-08):
Pickling selenium in this way stopped working in the latest selenium (4.x). Pickle fails to pickle an internal socket object. One option is to add a 'selenium=3.141.0' item to the install_requires component in setup.py which still works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know from using Protractor\C# architectures:

Basic usage can be deceiving, meaning when using ChromeDriver in C# you get a mask of all the fuss behind the scenes BUT declaring and initializing a webDriver creates and start a 'server' (in Protractor it's done manually). The webDriver uses some of this server's abilities and states.

I think of the webDriver not as an object but as an API. The representation of this API as an object is for the ease of use, so I beleave what you ask for is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pickle the webdriver object
It is enough to save the executor_url and session_id (instead of pickle.dump()), create a new webdriver object and attache it to the existing session (instead of pickle.load())

```
def attach_to_session(executor_url, session_id):
    original_execute = WebDriver.execute

    def new_command_execute(self, command, params=None):
        if command == "newSession":
            return {'success': 0, 'value': None, 'sessionId': session_id}
        else:
            return original_execute(self, command, params)

    WebDriver.execute = new_command_execute
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor_url)
    driver.session_id = session_id
    WebDriver.execute = original_execute
    return driver
```

Comment: What is the executor_url?

Comment: @BenjaminHobson it's URL to selenium hub + '/wd/hub'