# Can I save the web driver object by file when using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I use selenium in python to automatically control the browser(firefox).
Each time I run a process, python will create a browser object by webdriver
(such as driver = webdriver.Firefox()).
And I can use such driver.get("http://xxx.xxx") to control it.
But when I close the web or stop the process, the link between browser and process will finish.
So, when I run an A1 process and create a W browser, can I save the W object in file?
And then when I run an A2 process, A2 can directly read the file to control the W.

I guess I need save all the value in the driver object with some memory information about browser?
But I am not sure if it works.
Is there any better way?
Thank you!

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208188/pickling-selenium-webdriver-objects

Comment: Thank you for answer!
But I try the method like:
opt = selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
capabilities = opt.to_capabilities()
driver = selenium.webdriver.Remote(command_executor=EXECUTOR, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

It still not works. The error is "Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService".
I have downloaded the selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar and run it in java 15. 
I try to solve it by myself. But I count`t find any usefull way. Could you give any hint about that?