# How to save and restore selenium chrome driver (selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver) using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating boring routine work (login and basic stuff), it takes 10-12min. I want to save this object and use next time. I tried using pickle, `joblib` but facing below error.

```
import pickle

with open('company_data.pkl', 'wb') as output:

    pickle.dump(driver, output)
```

`AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'`

Can someone help me to save this object and load ?

Comment: Maybe this link would help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32858475/866930